# Find first of for char

Tags: c++, arrays, char, find

How to apply find_first_of function for char (char array). I know it can be done for a string but I want to know how to do it when I can declare only variable of type char. It doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char str[10];
  cin >> str;

  if(str[10].find_first_of('z')!=string::npos)
  {
     cout << "nazwa: " << str[10] << endl;
  }

  return (0);
}
```

Error: "'find_first_of'must have class\struct\union";
Compiler stressed word "str" in `if(**str**[10]...)` -> expression must have class type.

Comment: use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` with `std::find_first_of()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How exactly to write it? I do not know where this should be placed.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4664643731384deb

Answer (score 0):

`find_first_of` is a method on `string`. You can only use it on an object of that type:

```
std::string str
cin >> str;

if (str.find_first_of('z') != std::string::npos) {
    // ....
}
```

A `char` array, while serving the same purpose, is not a string, so neither your cin nor your function work. To use an array instead, you'd have to do:

```
char str[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cin >> str[i];
}

if (std::find(str, str + 10, 'z') != (str + 10)) {
    // ....
}
```